# to allow space in regular expression

Tags: regex

`[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{3,}` this is my currently using regular expression in login page. I would like to allow space in the regexp. How can i do it? I'm lack of knowledge in RegExp.

Answer (score 5):

This is just a character class, so just add space at the end of the class: `[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{3,}`

Comment: Just a hint: It's a good idea to put the hyphen at the start or end of the character class. That way, you can be sure it will never be accidentally interpreted as a range indicator. So `[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]{3,}` is preferable IMO.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-_\s]{3,}
```

This will allow all forms of whitespace...

Comment: You can use `\s` inside the character class just fine; no need for alternation.